# Does text from a rich text editor not inherit styles when rendered in an HTML document?

Tags: html, angular, rte

Just to make things clear, I have used an RTE in the backend to store some description. Later, through an api, I am receiving the description along with other details as a response. Now the styles are intact till now. For example, bold headings. But when I render it in the HTML document using innerHTML property, all I see is unformatted text. The headings are not bold anymore.

Here's a part of response:

```
</p>\r\n\n\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Features</span> \n </p>\r\n\n\r\n<p>Gives even skin tone, smoother complexion and sculpted facial features.
```

Clearly, font-style="bold" can be seen here. But after this, the rendered version does not contain those styles.

Here's the full response:

```
"cart_count":2,
"images":[
],
"success":true,
"message":"Sucessfully",
"data":{
"product_id":1,
"name":"Dr G Butterfly Gua Sha",
"category_id":1,
"category":"Skin Tool",
"description":"<p>Dr G Butterfly Rose Quartz Gua Sha is a beauty and wellness tool designed to heal and enhance natural beauty. It lifts and sculpts your face, drains the lymph node, which reduces puffy eyes and face. By scraping with repeated strokes on the surface of the skin, this tool helps stimulate muscles and increases the blood flow. \n </p>\r\n\n\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Features</span> \n </p>\r\n\n\r\n<p>Gives even skin tone, smoother complexion and sculpted facial features. Reduces the signs of ageing and gives younger-looking skin. Increases lymphatic function. Stimulates blood circulation. Improves the appearance of dark circles and reduces under-eye puffiness.  </p>\r\n\n\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">How To Use  \n</span></p>\r\n\n\r\n<p>Apply Dr G oil or Dr G gel as per your skin type covering the face and neck. </p>\r\n<p>Hold the butterfly gua sha tool firmly and sweep across gently up and out, starting with the neck, cheeks, jawline, chin, around the mouth, and slowly glide under the eyes, across your eyebrows and from your forehead up to your hairline. </p>\r\n<p>You can sweep it 3-5 times per area. </p>\r\n<p>Recommended at least a few times a week for best results.  </p>\r\n\n\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">About Dr G</span> \n </p>\r\n\n\r\n<p>Dr G offers luxury skincare products, backed by over a decade of dermatology expertise and on-ground practice. Made for Indian weather conditions, with variants for different skin types, including sensitive skin, and to address specific skin concerns - these innovative products are a perfect balance of nature and science. Drawing from ancient Ayurveda and combining natural extracts with skin-safe science, Dr G's range of products bridge modern skincare with holistic science.</p>",
"short_description":"Sculpts, Tones, Reduces Puffiness, Lifts",
"max_quantity":500,
"status":1,
"in_stock":1,
"measurement":[
{
"is_cart":true,
"ordered_quantity":2,
"is_wish":false,
"discounted_price":1400.0,
"weight":"200 Gram",
"price":1400.0,
"prod_id":1,
"percentage":100,
"max_quantity":500
}
]
}
}
```

Comment: I'd have to see the complete response from the backend, but if I had to wager a guess, I'd check whether the encoded quotation marks are the problem (ie. \").

Comment: @AldinBradaric, I was also thinking this initially. Is sit that the text is converted into string when sent as a response? The only reason for knowing this is that the client can provide anything in the description in any formatting (bold, italics, etc). We just don't want to hardcode anything.

Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Like  Aldin Bradaric said, the full response is needed to clarify this Problem.
But you should encode your HTML( for example to a Base64 string) before seinding it to the frondend and decode it there.

Comment: I have updated it with full response, please have a look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML from your response isn't valid. You can easily test it, if you copy the HTML string from your response to a text file with .html file ending and open it with your browser (index.html for example). Or use a validator like this one: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Let's pick one part from the HTML string which has wrong characters and gets displayed unformatted:

`<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Features</span> \n`

If you remove the backslashes `\` here this peace gets rendered correctly:

`<span style="font-weight: bold;">Features</span> \n`

[image]

I would reccomend you to encode the HTML before sending it to the frondend. You could use Base64 which can be easily encoded in the backend and decoded on the frontend before displaying it.

If this "wrong" characters are already there when you recive this HTML (on your Backend) you have to parse it first to clean it.

Comment: Responding here so that any other dev having a similar issue does not have to waste a lot of time, so the problem is not with the "\n", it's because of **DOMSanitization** in angular. 
More about it here: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer
Solution: Use a simple pipe to bypass the sanitization if you trust the external source.